# Citrix Desktop Lock and Sysprep Issue

Tags: citrix, sysprep

We are currently creating an image to essentially convert our desktops into thin clients to point to our XenDesktop environment.  To do this, we are using Citrix's Desktop Lock tool which locks down all user profiles except the one with which the tool was installed (typically the administrator profile).  This works great except that when we sysprep the image, it does something that causes the tool to no longer recognize the administrator profile as the one used to install the tool and therefore locks down the administrator profile.  Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how to get around it?  I was told that it might have something to do with sysprep deleting and re-creating the administrator profile, but I don't see anything in the unattend file to alter that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SysPrep deletes the Administrator account, but it definitely changes the SID of the machine. This would change the SID of the Administrator account. It makes sense that Desktop Lock would keep track of the SID of the excluded user, rather than the name of the account. If that is the case, when the machine SID changes, the Administrator SID changes, and the exclusion is broken.

Note: I don't actually know that that is how the exclusion works. I'm just saying it makes sense.

I would suggest not including Desktop Lock in your SysPrepped image. Rather, use the SysPref.inf file to automatically log on as Administrator after mini-setup. Then run The Desktop Lock installation silently when the Administrator logs on. Of course, this should be followed by a reboot or log off.